# Numbers of new post since the last visit of user

Tags: posts

I need to count the number of new post since the last visit of the user on my blog, is it possible?

Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: What have you already tried.

Comment: Hi! I tried get all the numbers of post, but only i need the last post. I guess define a cookie for this purpose.

Comment: Please show us the code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is possible to get what you want by

Store the last date time a user login as a user meta

Use the usermeta to get posts published after the date - time uring $wpdb